# TSQL combination of a left and right join on same two tables with different columns for each join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to roll these to into one insert statement.  I was thinking something with a full outer join but that doesn't work because I am doing one join with columnA and the other with columnB so I'm not sure ... do I have to go with two insert statements ... because I tried that and I didn't get the results I was looking for.

```
   FROM MainTable RIGHT JOIN SubTable ON MainTable.ColumnA = SubTable.ColumnA
   WHERE (((MainTable.ColumnA) Is Null) AND ((Left([SubTable].[ColumnA],3))="001"));

   FROM SubTable LEFT JOIN MainTable ON SubTable.ColumnB = MainTable.ColumnB
   WHERE (((MainTable.ColumnA) Is Null) AND ((Left([SubTable].[ColumnA],3))="001"));
```

**FYI ... this is coming from an ACCESS insert query that I can't open in SQL View to see exactly what that code looks like**

Comment: Try `UNION` the two queries.

Comment: Where are you inserting to? Can you give more information?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember access correctly, it can't do a full join. This looks like Access' attempt to do so. Doing quick check on google, I found this link that says to change it to a union like wdosanjos suggested: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/join-tables-and-queries-HA010096320.aspx